# How can I set the culture for dotnet logging?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, culture, .net-core-3.0

I'm using logging in dotnetcore 3.1. When I use composite formatting of dates in a logger, I get a different format than if I convert the date to a string in my application code.

This code:

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
_logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
_logger.LogInformation("TEST date via format string {}", DateTime.Today);
_logger.LogInformation("TEST date with concatentation:" + DateTime.Today);
```

produces this output (note the change in order of days and months):

```
TEST date via format string 08/26/2020 00:00:00
TEST date with concatentation:26/08/2020 00:00:00
```

I'm surprised the logger doesn't inherit the culture from the application. Am I missing something, and if not how can I control the culture of the logger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This interested me, and I decided to dig around a bit.

Judging by the dotnet LogValuesFormatter in the [Logging repository](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/0560d97f9ff1c479af7578c346f15d9036bc8717/src/Logging/Logging.Analyzers/src/LogValuesFormatter.cs#L127), when using the braces { }, the call to the Format method uses the invariant culture.

Which, according to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#how-standard-format-strings-work) is set up as MM/dd/yyyy.

However, the concatenation does appear to use the current culture.

I would suggest that if you want to use the braces formatting that you simply call ToString and add the culture in order to cast the date to a string in the current culture, before the formatter gets a hold of it. You could also use string interpolation which uses a similar syntax to the braces, but appears to also use the current culture:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Current culture is "+  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
_logger.LogInformation("TEST date via format string {}", DateTime.Today);
_logger.LogInformation("TEST date via cultured format string {}", DateTime.Today.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
_logger.LogInformation("TEST date with concatentation:" + DateTime.Today);
_logger.LogInformation($"TEST date with string interpolation: {DateTime.Today}");
```

This code gives me this output:

```
Current culture is en-GB
TEST date via format string 09/12/2020 00:00:00
TEST date via cultured format string 12/09/2020 00:00:00
TEST date with concatentation:12/09/2020 00:00:00
TEST date with string interpolation: 12/09/2020 00:00:00
```

Comment: The linked source code illustrates that the answer to my question is "No. I cannot control the culture of the logger". While I'm ambivalent about MS's decision to enforce InvariantCulture, the choice of MM/dd/yyyy for that date format is as objectionable ever :) 
 btw @reisclef check your second link, it's the same as the first. Thanks!

Comment: Totally agree with your statement @TrevorJ. And thanks for pointing out the link mistake. That's what I get for answering a question in the late evening! I've corrected it now. :)